# Как с помощью клиентского скрипта загружать картинки в папку ?

Tags: javascript, html, браузер

Как на клиенте с помощью js сохранять  изображения по url?

Comment: Так принято делать только в NodeJS. В обычном JavaScript применяется автоматическое кэширование

Comment: NodeJS это разновидность JS. Для начала разберитесь с терминологией

Comment: Одно другому не мешает

Comment: Я не понимаю, о чем толкует php5engineer и при чем тут севрерный NodeJS и непонятное кэширование, но одному я могу сказать точно. Клиентский JavaScript не имеет абсолютно никакого доступа к файловой системе, поэтому задуманное у Вас не выйдет. Скачать можно, отобразить можно, сохранить без прямого участия пользователя нельзя.

Comment: @AlexKrass, используя NodeJS, сделать приложение, корректно работающее в то время, когда устройство находится оффлайн, вполне возможно. Например, передавая эти изображения в JSONP

Comment: Возможно вас не так поняли. Если вам нужно открывать окно сохранения файла, то можно попробовать вариант с новым html5 атрибутом download:
http://pixelscommander.com/javascript/javascript-file-download-ignore-content-type/
Посмотрите пример в конце статьи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью клиентского Javascript невозможно полноценно работать с файловой системой без участия пользователя в выборе папки и т.д., как уже сказал [Alex Krass](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16416/alex-krass). Об этом хорошо написано [в статье от Mozilla](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/why-no-filesystem-api-in-firefox/comment-page-1/).

Тем не менее, если Вы разрабатываете мобильное приложение через PhoneGap - возможностей более чем достаточно. Начните изучение, с [документации cordova.file](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html).